# Rake db:reset execute in development and test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake, environment

I got a Ruby on Rails v5 application and I'm trying to run the following Rake task in development environment:

```
rake db:reset
```

Sadly, **Rake runs the task in both development and test environment**. Since I don't use the test environment, I don't wanna double my database. I have read somewhere that Rake run task in both environment when there is no RAILS_ENV defined. So I try to add the following line to my .bash_profile without any success:

```
export RAILS_ENV="development"
```

I also tried to add *RAILS_ENV=development* at the end of my task but it also did not worked.

Is there a way to use Rake in development only ?

**Update #1**

Thanks to Taryn East for the quick comment. I'm trying to update my post as quick as possible to make it easy for you to answer efficiently.

*What do you actually observe when you run that command?*

The command are simply executed twice. Since I have different database for my development and test environment, it does not show me any error at the moment. On the other hand, it does force me to use two database for no reason at all. I also tried to set the same database for the two environments, but then I was getting error since Rake tried to run the task twice on the database.

eg of output for rake db:drop

```
Dropped database 'db'
Database 'db' does not exist
```

It did drop my database, but as you can see Rake tried to run the command another time for the other environment.

*Why aren't you using the test environment?*

Because I don't see any advantage of it for my current project. I don't have time to create and update tests. I'm also not used to use both development and test environment at the same time.

*If you want to run a rake task in just a single environment, you can also add RAILS_ENV to the command line.*

As I said in my post, it does not work. Here's what I did:

```
RAILS_ENV=development rake db:drop
```

And here's the output:

```
Dropped database 'db'
Database 'db' does not exist
```

**Update #2**

Here's my database.yml configuration:

```
default: &default
  adapter:mysql2
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db
  username: something
  password: something
  host: localhost
  port: 3306

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db_test
  username: something
  password: something
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
```

I don't know if it can help, but my environment is development according to the *rake about* task.

Comment: How do you know that it's running in multiple environments? what do you *actually observe* when you run that command? what error message(s) are you getting? Secondly: why aren't you using the test environment? you definitely should have one of those set up! it won't double your database... the test database is structure-only without any data except for when your tests (which you should have!) are actually running. Thirdly: if you want to run a rake task in just a single environment, you can also add RAILS_ENV to the command line. eg you could run: `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:reset`

Comment: Thank you for you're answer. I answered you in the Update #1 section.

Comment: " I don't have time to create and update tests." you don't have time to fix bugs that could have been caught early by those tests either... ;)

Comment: The problem does sound odd though - it sounds like rake is running simultaneously on two environments, which it shouldn't be. Can you show us your `config/database.yml`? (just delete out the username/password) ?

Comment: You're definitely right about the time lost. I just can't understand that I can't run my task in a single environment. It makes no sense. Anyway, I did another update in the post.

Comment: Note: not really sure of port-numbers being the same. affecting anything. I'd be guessing not as that should be the port for the db-server, not affect whether it tries to talk to both of them...  Also - sounds silly, but just to make certain it isn't some weird duplicated-ness in db.yml, try being explicit about settings instead of using the defaults? if it affects nothing you can change it back... but might be worth checking in case of some kind of weird caching-of-config bug (in rails) or something.

Answer (score 1):

> I have read somewhere that Rake run task in both environment when
>   there is no RAILS_ENV defined.

This is not correct. If the environment is `development`, `test` is also added to current environments. See: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f507085fa2a7625324e6f4e3ecef9b27dabefb4f/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb#L339

So this is expected behaviour.

On the other hand what you're saying will be true for any other env. E.g. `RAILS_ENV=test rails db:drop` will only execute for test env.

Comment: How do you disable this? Expected or not, this is not desirable behavior.

Comment: You can't. This is a long-running discussion in the rails community, for example: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27299

Comment: Actually, this is not true. You can use the SKIP_TEST_DATABASE environment variable starting with rails 6.1: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39027